# Using the SFTP object from SSH2

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ssh, sftp

I'm using [SSH2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2) to get and put files on a server via SFTP. I don't understand how to read or use this documentation though. I understand that there is an `sftp` object that is returned using the following method `conn.sftp(function(err, sftp)`. However, I'm not sure what this `sftp` actually is or how I can even see what methods it has. The documentation doesn't seem to offer anything for that.

Looking through other places, I see that there is supposedly a `fastPut` method among other methods.

How can I see what methods is on this SFTP object if the documentation doesn't provide that? If the documentation does provide it, where would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Client.sftp` [method](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2#client-methods) returns [`SFTPStream` instance](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2-streams/blob/master/SFTPStream.md).

`SFTPStream` has `fastPut` [method](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2-streams/blob/master/SFTPStream.md#sftpstream-methods):

> fastPut(< string >localPath, < string >remotePath[, < object >options], < function >callback) - (void)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!